# ansible playbook role to install promtail

Tags: ansible, roles, host, promtail

I keep getting this error when i want to run my ansible playbook to install promtail on my instances.

### #This is my playbook

- hosts: all
  roles:

  - role: patrickjahns.promtail
    vars:
    promtail_config_scrape_configs:
    - job_name: system
    static_configs:
    - targets:
    - localhost
    labels:
    job: varlogs
    **path**: /var/log/*log

[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/emediong/dynamic-inventory/roles/inventory.txt as an inventory
source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! the role 'patrickjahns.promtail' was not found in /home/emediong/dynamic-inventory/roles/roles:/home/emediong/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/emediong/dynamic-inventory/roles

The error appears to be in '/home/emediong/dynamic-inventory/roles/promtail.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

roles:
- role: patrickjahns.promtail
^ here

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your issue. You need to install the [role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/patrickjahns/promtail) with ansible-galaxy using the below command before you can run the playbook.

`ansible-galaxy install patrickjahns.promtail`

**Testing**

Before installing (same error):

```
The error appears to be in 'test.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - role: patrickjahns.promtail
      ^ here
```

After installing (it works!):

```
 ____________ 
< PLAY [all] >
 ------------ 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

skipping: no hosts matched
 ____________ 
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------ 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```